# How can I make my iPhone 5S go back to charging from my Dell Windows laptop USB port?

Tags: iphone, windows, usb, charging

My iPhone 5s, when connected to my Windows 10 Dell laptop, has recently started connecting & charging then immediately disconnecting and ending charging. I get the "double buzz" of connection, immediately followed by a single buzz indicating it has stopped charging, and the "charging" lightning-bolt symbol disappears.

How can I fix this (asking and answering for future generations)?

Comment: In my experience unless you have a charging only cable, installing iTunes will allow the device to charge and not disconnect like it does. So it's basically a driver issue, which you discovered by disabling the appropriate device in device manager. And, yes I agree, its annoying.

Comment: @SteveChambers cool, good to have another fix available.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by disabling the non-USB 3.0 device in the Windows device manager. For some reason, iPhone is not happy when a non-USB 3.0 device is active. I'll leave it to someone else to explain exactly why.

Anyhow, the fix is:
1) Open Device Manager
2) Find the "Universal Serial Bus controllers" section
3) Find the USB device that does NOT seems like it's a 3.0 device (in my case it was called "USB Composite Device")
4) Right click on that device, and click "disable".

Voila, my iPhone charges and connects again.

See below what my Device Manager window looked like after I disabled the non-USB 3.0 device. 
[image: Device manager showing my three USB devices]

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I should mention that it is my somewhat informed opinion that after this fix, if you connect a non-USB 3.0 device to your computer, it won't work, or maybe would work at USB 1.1 speeds. Anyhow, if that happens, I expect you could just re-enable the device you disabled.